# Where to add brackets in (a || b && c) to make it more readable?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, logical-operators

```
if (a || b && c) {...}
```

I found this in our javascript code and want to add brackets to make it more readable.

is this `(a || (b && c))` or `((a || b) && c)` ?

Comment: well what is it supposed to be.... where you stick parenthesis changes its meaning. `( a || b && c)` does not equal `( a || b) && c`

Comment: Check the documentation on the [operator precedence (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Comment: the implied parentheses are `a || (b && c)` - `c` will only be evaluated if `b` is truthy. `b` will only be evaluated if `a` is falsey.

Comment: If you want to make it more readable use descriptive variable names and split complex expressions into parts `const isSomethingMeaningful = b && c; const shouldDoSomething = a || isSomethingMeaningful; if (shouldDoSomething) {}`

Comment: https://chortle.ccsu.edu/java5/Notes/chap40/ch40_16.html     check this site it's helpful

Comment: @Andreas - ok, looks like OR has precedence of 5 and AND has precedence of 6, therefore (a || b && c) is the same as ((a || b) && c), right?

Comment: @NadimBaraky No it's not, because this isn't Java

Comment: _"The following table is **ordered from highest (20) to lowest (1) precedence**"_

Comment: @Andreas you are right... misread... sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(a || (b && c))
```

as precedence of `&&` is higher than `||`.
e.g.

```
true || true && false // Gives true
(true || true) && false // Gives false
true || (true && false) // Gives true
```